# Connecting to AWS S3 works through AWS CLI and not through Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, port, aws-cli

I am trying to connect to my s3 bucket through Visual Studio and the connection does not go through. It works when I use the AWS CLI but not when running a s3 call from my program in Visual Studio. The s3 call from the program works when I run it when I am at home but not when I am in a more restricted network.

It may be a firewall issue but I'm thinking it may not be due to the fact that the call works using the AWS CLI. Does Visual Studio use different ports to connect to an s3 bucket? How is an s3 call from Visual Studio different than from the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access keys to your AWS resources in Visual Studio. Here is how you do it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html

You can take the values of access key id and secret from `%HOME%\.aws\credentials` file.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but that does not fix the issue unfortunately. The program itself works at home but not in the workplace.